# CAML Query Condition use to REST API in SharePoint

Tags: caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api

How to use and understood CAML query condition and how to apply the condition to SharePoint's REST API? Please see my CAML query condition and my REST API code also.

CAML query condition:

```
"<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <And>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Author'  LookupId='True' />
            <Value Type='User'>111</Value>
          </Neq>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='PIC'  LookupId='True' />
            <Value Type='UserMulti'>111</Value>
          </Neq>
        </And>
        <And>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='MasterPIC'  LookupId='True'  />
            <Value Type='UserMulti'>111</Value>
          </Neq>
          <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='GatekeepingPic'  LookupId='True' />
            <Value Type='UserMulti'>111</Value>
          </Neq>
        </And>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>"
```

REST API condition:

```
http://.../_api/lists/getbytitle('Library')/items?$select=TitleNew,Author/Id,Author/Title,MeetingDate,NgoName,Staff,MPicmailid,MasterPIC/Id,MasterPIC/Title,Editor/Id,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,MasterPIC,Editor&$filter=(Author/Id ne '111')and (MasterPIC/Id ne '111') and (Editor/Id ne '111')
```

How to understand the camel query condition?
Please, anyone, Is both conditions are true? if it false in rest API please update my rest API condition? I need condition only to my rest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Query = "[Your CAML Query]";
var endpointUrl = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[ListName]')/getitems"
function getData() {
    var retval = '';    
    var datatoload = {
        'query': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
            },
            'ViewXml': Query
        }
    };

    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(datatoload),
        url: endpointUrl,
        success: function(data) {            
            for(var i=0;i<=data.d.results.length;i++)
            {
                console.log(data.d.results[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            failure(data); // Do something with the error
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rest API `$filter` must be changed to match the CAML query.

```
http://...//_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Library')/items?$select=TitleNew,Author/Id,Author/Title,MeetingDate,NgoName,Staff,MPicmailid,MasterPIC/Id,MasterPIC/Title,Editor/Id,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,MasterPIC,Editor&$filter=(Author/Id ne '111') and (PIC/Id ne '111') and (MasterPIC/Id ne '111') and (GatekeepingPic/Id ne '111')
```

*Note:*In SharePoint rest API, 
`$select` - which fields to return in results.
`$expand` - used to retrieve information from Lookup columns.
`$filter` - specifies which items to return.
For Reference check this [**link**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: Please can you change my rest api as match camel query condition.

Comment: @Hasanshali check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use your CAML query in SharePoint REST API too, then I don't think that you will need any overload to convert such big CAML to REST API Condition syntax.

Here is the working example:

```
var viewXml = "YOUR CAML QUERY";
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/getitems";
var queryPayload = {
    'query': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
        'ViewXml': viewXml
    }
};
return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications.